# Software & Updates : server changes automatically to "Custom servers"

Tags: server, software-sources

I set "Server for India" In Software & Updates as following:

[image: india]

**But It randomly (after some days) & automatically sets to "Custom servers"** as following:

[image: custom]

How to stop changing this? Because this download all source (repositories updates) from beginning while reload or `sudo apt-get update`.